# Sharepoint 2013 - Expand All / Collapse All for Group By list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list web part  with 2 levels of Group By. 
I am trying to add a button to Expand or Collapse (toggle).
Expectation - Even when the list is partially expanded, clicking on Expand should expand all the groups and clicking on Collapse should collapse all the groups.

I tried copying few codes from net but being a non-coder, I guess I am not getting the desired result.

Example:
Used this code but this does not toggle the switch and for a partially opened list, it closes the open items and closes the closed ones.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/Javascript">
    function collapseGroups() {
        $("img[id^='img_']").click();
    }
    function expandGroups() {
        $("img[id^='img_']").click();
    }
</script>
<input id="btnExpand1" onclick="expandGroups()" type="button" value="Expand All" />
<input id="btnExpand2" onclick="collapseGroups()" type="button" value="Collapse All" />
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to get the all the anchor tags whose click expands or collapse a group (for a particular group), Then call 'click()' event iteratively. e.g.

```
$('.ms-listviewtable').find('tbody').each(function() {  //loop by id of your list view table
    if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('titl0-') > -1) { //for each 'tbody' with 'id' containing 'titl0' string, you can inspect the html of your list view table to see what id's are being formed' 
    //console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    var a = $(this).find('a');
    a.click();
     }
});
```

you can set a flag to track if state is currently `'Expanded'` or `'Collapsed'`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide an example of the loop body.

Comment: Code in the answer  already contains the loop. you just need to call this piece of code in click events of your buttons

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013, you can modify the code as below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function collapseGroups() {
    $("img.ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();
}
function expandGroups() {
    $("img.ms-commentexpand-icon").click();
}
</script>
<input id="btnExpand1" onclick="expandGroups()" type="button" value="Expand All" />
<input id="btnExpand2" onclick="collapseGroups()" type="button" value="Collapse All" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked this code. The behavior still remains the same: 1. Two buttons are created but clicking on any of them does an expand / collapse. 2. Suppose my list is partially open, then clicking on any of these buttons closes the list partially, clicking it again opens the list partially

Comment: You need add the code into a script editor web part in list view page.